# solltest - Konjuktiv II or Präteritum?

Tags: german-to-english, grammar-identification, tense

Some modal verbs have different forms in `Präteritum` vs. `Konjuktiv II`, for example

```
können, konnte, könnte
```

So if I see something like

```
Wenn Ich mehr Geld hätte, könnte Ich mehr reisen
```

I think the meaning is some imaginary situation right now.

But a verb `sollen` is the same in `Praeteritum` and in `Konjuktiv II`. So, how do I understand the meaning of the following sentence

```
Du solltest mehr studieren.
```

Is it `Konjuktiv II` (an advice to a person, that he should study more right now) or `Präteritum` (telling a person that he should have studied more in the past, but did not do this)?

Comment: I wouldn't read "solltest" as "should have studied more", that would be "du hättest mehr ... sollen". To me it rather sounds like a description of tasks in the past.

Comment: @DonHolgo, good point, I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible. Most of the time context will resolve the ambiguity.

Note that translation into English can be a bit tricky, because “shall” is a defective verb. If “du solltest” is past tense, it means something like “you were supposed to”.

Answer (score 0):

"Mehr studieren" is to study more, and sounds more like English. Experience tells me Germans would most likely say "Du solltest **weiter** studieren," (You should continue with your studies.)

If you have learned it or are learning 'sollte' along with 'hätte' and 'könnte,' then the meaning is most likely Konjunktiv II, and it's meant to be (a) *Ratschlag*, some advice.

Most frequently these verbs are grouped together in German coursebooks so you learn them at the same time; it's a big help.

A couple of things to this sentence:

> Wenn Ich mehr Geld hätte, könnte Ich mehr reisen

1. The word 'ich' is always lowercase (unless it's at the beginning of a sentence).
2. It means "If I had more money, I could travel more." It's all about imagining something you don't currently have.
3. It's a perfect accompaniment to "Du solltest weiter studieren."

Comment: I'm not convinced of your translation using *weiter*, since the meaning is different as you observe. I understand *mehr studieren* as *invest more effort* or *more intense learning*. But there are plenty of other similar phrases, where *mehr* can't be replaced easily, like *mehr Vokabeln lernen*, *mehr auf deine Prüfung lernen*.